# Unable to change svg colour using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm having trouble changing the colour of an svg image with jquery or vanila javascript. I've tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work, the original colour is black and i can change it if i open the svg image in my IDE and add/change the fill attribute. But not with JS. What am I doing wrong? Other lines of code work fine so it is not a problem with the files or so.

So far i've tried these lines of codes and put id on the img tag aswell as the svg element it self

html:

```
 <img src="import/splash.svg">
```

JS:

```
$('#myId').css({fill:"#f8b9d4"});

$("myId").attr("fill", "yellow");

document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("fill", "#f8b9d4");

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 588 497" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>random title</title>
<g>
<path
    d="M259.952694,496.613554 C253.376792,496.613554 250.627732,488.109987 250.038987,483.084288 L246.271494,450.855246 C245.492831,444.196255 243.408484,440.818093 240.070679,440.818093 C236.607054,440.818093 232.400376,443.96598 231.070952,445.174331 L199.957676,473.559913 C195.010319,478.077582 191.435117,480.178547 188.70505,480.178547 C187.190455,480.178547 185.884771,479.528079 185.020645,478.350589 C182.383162,474.756395 184.650306,466.661151 185.407603,464.263439 L192.935467,440.450127 C193.543204,438.531958 194.03699,435.934833 192.949711,434.446352 C191.893294,433.002977 189.478964,432.791694 188.135296,432.791694 C187.140602,432.791694 186.411793,432.903271 186.3382,432.91514 L127.318884,443.085236 C118.696618,444.573716 112.519544,442.940424 109.001317,438.313553 C103.842676,431.523993 106.712808,420.883851 106.838629,420.439918 "
    id="myId" fill=""></path>
</g>
```

UPDATE - created a completley new project but the problem is the same. (The div is for testing and working fine)
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<script src="tmo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="splash.svg" alt="">
<div id="h"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#myId').css({fill:"blue"});
  $("#h").text("heasdadasdsadasdsad");

});
```

SVG file:

```
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 588 497" version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>random title</title>
<g>
    <path
        d="M259.952694,496.613554 C253.376792,496.613554 250.627732,488.109987 250.038987,483.084288 L246.271494,450.855246 C245.492831,444.196255 243.408484,440.818093 240.070679,440.818093 C236.607054,440.818093 232.400376,443.96598 231.070952,445.174331 L199.957676,473.559913 "
        id="myId"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's because you're using an `<img>` tag rather than putting the `<svg>` directly in the HTML.

If you cannot put the `<svg>` directly in your HTML, embed it using the `<object>` tag, e.g. like this:

```
<object id="img" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml">Your browsser doesn't support SVG</object>
```

Then, you can access elements inside the `<object>` like this:

```
document.getElementById("img").contentDocument.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("fill", "#f8b9d4");
```

Comment: Thank you, however it didnt work to embed it very well, but I put the svg file directly in the html file and it worked now!

Answer (score 2):

Your Jquery css works fine. You don't need to have an empty `fill=""` attribute on the `path`.

Note: Scroll down on the code snippet to see result, your viewbox is a bit big :)

```js
$('#myId').css({fill:"blue"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 588 497" version="1.1"  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>random title</title>
<g>
<path
    d="M259.952694,496.613554 C253.376792,496.613554 250.627732,488.109987 250.038987,483.084288 L246.271494,450.855246 C245.492831,444.196255 243.408484,440.818093 240.070679,440.818093 C236.607054,440.818093 232.400376,443.96598 231.070952,445.174331 L199.957676,473.559913 C195.010319,478.077582 191.435117,480.178547 188.70505,480.178547 C187.190455,480.178547 185.884771,479.528079 185.020645,478.350589 C182.383162,474.756395 184.650306,466.661151 185.407603,464.263439 L192.935467,440.450127 C193.543204,438.531958 194.03699,435.934833 192.949711,434.446352 C191.893294,433.002977 189.478964,432.791694 188.135296,432.791694 C187.140602,432.791694 186.411793,432.903271 186.3382,432.91514 L127.318884,443.085236 C118.696618,444.573716 112.519544,442.940424 109.001317,438.313553 C103.842676,431.523993 106.712808,420.883851 106.838629,420.439918 "
    id="myId"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the same. I've updated the OP with the html-tag if it helps. The only difference I see in your post is the link to jquery (and the fill-attribute is gone), and I already have that in the index.html file and if I add it I get an error in the svg-file saying "Multiple Root Tags"

Comment: @Halalbin I have also added an ending `</svg>` tag to my snippet as it was not in your original code. Could it be this?

Comment: No unfortunately this was a copy/past typo from my side. It is in the original file. Also I created a completely new project with only the necessary files to see if it worked, and still the sam problem. Gona uppdate the OP. It cant be a problem with the selectors,  that jquery dont find the id bc it is so deep down in the structure or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This- 

$('#myId').css({fill:"blue"});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 588 497" version="1.1"  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<title>random title</title>
<g>
<path
    d="M259.952694,496.613554 C253.376792,496.613554 250.627732,488.109987 250.038987,483.084288 L246.271494,450.855246 C245.492831,444.196255 243.408484,440.818093 240.070679,440.818093 C236.607054,440.818093 232.400376,443.96598 231.070952,445.174331 L199.957676,473.559913 C195.010319,478.077582 191.435117,480.178547 188.70505,480.178547 C187.190455,480.178547 185.884771,479.528079 185.020645,478.350589 C182.383162,474.756395 184.650306,466.661151 185.407603,464.263439 L192.935467,440.450127 C193.543204,438.531958 194.03699,435.934833 192.949711,434.446352 C191.893294,433.002977 189.478964,432.791694 188.135296,432.791694 C187.140602,432.791694 186.411793,432.903271 186.3382,432.91514 L127.318884,443.085236 C118.696618,444.573716 112.519544,442.940424 109.001317,438.313553 C103.842676,431.523993 106.712808,420.883851 106.838629,420.439918 "
    id="myId"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```